# Replace Spaces in InValid XML File

Tags: c#, xml

**My Question**

I have an xml file with invalid syntax first of all, second i cant do anything to change it, due to the company thats feeding the xml.

I have element nodes that i need to gut out the space, how can i do that VIA C# .NET

I also have the option to get the data via a CSV format instead, thinking it might be easier to replace the values as a CSV rather then some XML String, but i just don't know how or the best way.

**Example**

Provided:
`<Avg Pos> value </Avg Pos>`

Required:
`<AvgPos> value </AvgPos>`

Comment: `Provided value Required value` ... looks the same for me? Did you forget some formatting in that?

Comment: "gut out the space"  What does this mean?  You need to explain yourself better when asking questions.

Comment: Like... post an example of the bad XML, and then post an example of what you want the XML to be.

Comment: If you want to maintain spaces you type in, you have to add `\`` before and after that section, otherwise multiple spaces are stripped to a single one ;-)

Comment: I fixed your formatting.

Comment: sorry guys, finally got the xml to show

Comment: Go for the CSV format. Clearly, the provider has no clue how to produce XML, so this is likely to be only the first of many problems you have.

Comment: Agreed.  If someone who's claiming to produce XML can't be bothered to check to see if what they're emitting is actually XML, there will be other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really what i was looking for...

### iReportPath

> `TextReader origXML = new StreamReader(iReportPath + iFileName);`
>
> `string validXMLString = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(origXML.ReadToEnd().ToString());`
>
> `validXMLString = validXMLString.Replace("Avg Pos", "AvgPos");`
>
> `validXMLString = validXMLString.Replace("Avg CPC", "AvgCPC");`
>
> `validXMLString = validXMLString.Replace("Gr. Rev", "Gr.Rev");`
>
> `validXMLString = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(validXMLString);`
>
> `origXML.Close();`
>
> > > `validXMLString` value is what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you never have any attributes inside the tags you could:

1. figure out all the element names
2. determine their malformed open and close tag equivalent.
3. replace all malformed tags with their wellformed equivalent in the entire document

But if my employer gave me that stuff and said it was XML, I'd know it was time to switch jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to be better off getting the CSV, because the XML they're feeding you is malformed.  In XML, because of the way tag naming works, there's a BIG difference between "TagName" and "Tag Name".  It sounds like they're delivering completely invalid XML (NO XML client will be able to read that properly, according to the example you give); you should try to get them to correct the error, but if they won't / can't, try dealing with the CSV.

Comment: the CSV has the same format for the element node, i need to convert the Invalid XML to Valid XML in order to import the data into a SQL Database.  Any other solutions?  I already put in a request to the company to change their XML, but they wont for the time being.

Comment: You've got some funny company there if they call that XML I don't wanna see what they call HTML Transitional 4.0 ...

Comment: Where is the valid XML specified?

Answer (score 0):

You better tell them what XML really means, 'cause that thing you posted there is far away from anything that has the right of being called XML...

In that case, go for the CSV, read in every row and strip out the spaces (e.g. `_Row.Replace(" ", "");`), save it in a new .XML and you should be good to go.